# repeat character and separate by comma

Tags: r, paste, repeat

I want to write something like this in R: `"Cat","Cat","Cat","Cat"`
This is what I could get:

```
paste(rep("Cat", 4), sep=",")

# [1] "Cat" "Cat" "Cat" "Cat"
```

The repeated words were not separated by comma (later I wanted to use it for other command).

Could you please help me with that? I apologize if I'm repeating the question but I couldn't find answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to use `collapse` instead of `sep`

```
paste(rep("Cat", 4), collapse=",")
#[1] "Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat"
```

Comment: @mad For that you may need `paste(rep("'Cat'", 4), collapse=",")` or `cat(paste(rep('"Cat"', 4), collapse=","))`

Comment: or `toString(dQuote(rep("Cat", 4)))`

Comment: @rawr It is unclear why the OP wanted the quotes.  I was commenting based on some other question where the OP specified about the fancy quotes

Comment: it appears the double quotes are non ascii but the singles are not? `x <- sprintf('s - %s, d - %s', shQuote('text'), dQuote('text')); rm_nonascii <- function(x) gsub('[^\x20-\x7E]', '', x); rm_nonascii(x)` this is outside my paygrade

Comment: @rawr Thanks for the function.  It looks that way